# kodi 17.1 eating cpu after upgrading to stretch

Tags: pi-3, kodi

After upgrading raspbian to stretch, kodi is unusable and eats all CPU:

```
 PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
1051 kodi      20   0  960812 233632  80332 R 92,9 31,1   1:11.49 llvmpipe-3
1048 kodi      20   0  960812 233632  80332 R 92,5 31,1   1:11.46 llvmpipe-0
1049 kodi      20   0  960812 233632  80332 R 89,3 31,1   1:10.87 llvmpipe-1
1050 kodi      20   0  960812 233632  80332 R 89,0 31,1   1:10.68 llvmpipe-2
 961 kodi      20   0  960812 233632  80332 S  6,8 31,1   0:21.20 kodi.bin
```

I can start an X session and it seems to have hardware acceleration:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ glxinfo | grep direct
direct rendering: Yes
    GL_ARB_direct_state_access, GL_ARB_draw_buffers,
    GL_ARB_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_draw_instanced, GL_ARB_enhanced_layouts,
    GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_occlusion_query2,
```

running from a terminal I see this messages:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ kodi
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/kodi/kodi-xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
```

I have 256MB assigned to GPU in memory split

debug log: https://pastebin.com/fCh9fT02

what is making kodi so slow?

*EDIT*

seems that it is not using the correct drivers:

```
GL_VENDOR = VMware, Inc.
GL_RENDERER = Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.9, 128 bits)
GL_VERSION = OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 13.0.6
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: it also appears a thermometer on screen when kodi is running, so "Throttling arm due to temperature"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, changed driver with:

```
raspi-config -> advanced options -> GL Driver -> GL (Fake KMS)
```

then Xserver was crashing with

```
(EE) xf86OpenConsole: Cannot open virtual console 7 (Permission denied)
```

(this bug: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=860486)

until it is fixed, added this to `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config`

```
allowed_users=anybody
needs_root_rights=yes
```

Comment: Thanks, this finally worked after many hours of searching for solution!

Comment: For some reason, the 'Fake KMS' doesn't work for me, the original driver (3rd option) does work